# How to determine which DataRow is bound to a DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

When I use a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) as a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)'s [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx), I often have to find which row(s) a user has selected and read specific values from the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) (not the DataGridView)

I wanted to know if there is any reliable way of determining which [`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) a [`DataGridViewRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.aspx) is bound to especially when the user has sorted the DataGridView on a column other than the default order.

Currently, I use code of this sort:

```
Dim sorting = ""

If DataGrid.SortOrder <> SortOrder.None Then
    'get the actual row if the results are sorted'
    sorting = "[" & DataGrid.SortedColumn.Name & "]" & 
              If(DataGrid.SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending, "", " DESC")
End If

'return the selected row after sorting'
Dim selectedRowIndices = (From r In DataGrid.SelectedRows Select 
                          DirectCast(r, DataGridViewRow).Index).ToArray
SelectedDataRow = (DataTable.Select("", sorting).Where(
                   Function(r As DataRow, i As Integer) i = selectedRowIndex)
                  ).FirstOrDefault
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem will give you a dataViewRow for the current item in the Databound dataTable (dataview).

So:

```
Dim drv as DataRowView = myDataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem

Dim dr as DataRow = drv.Row
```

Will give you the DataRow from your datagridviewrow.

Comment: I'm going to try it out in a moment.