# How to determine a DataGridViewRow from the DataRow it is bound to

Tags: c#, datagridview, datarow

I would like to change the forecolor of a `DataGridViewRow` when a `DataTable` event is fired (specifically the `DataColumnChangeEvent`). In order to do so I need to get the associated `DataGridViewRow` of the row the event occurred on.

I have the following:

```
private void DataColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
     {
     DataColumn col = e.Column;
     DataRow row = e.Row;

     if (col != null && row != null)
        {
        if (col.ColumnName == "abc")
           {
           String str = col.ToString();

           if (str == "1")
              {
              DataGridViewRow dgvr = <somehow get row's associated DataGridViewRow> 
              ChangeRowForeColor(dgvr, "Purple");
              }
           }
        }
```

The following questions are the reverse direction (getting a `DataRow` from a `DataGridViewRow`), so I know that it can be found one way at least, but I can't seem to find info on the reverse problem.

[How do I get a DataRow from a row in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822314/how-do-i-get-a-datarow-from-a-row-in-a-datagridview)

[How to determine which DataRow is bound to a DataGridViewRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014046/how-to-determine-which-datarow-is-bound-to-a-datagridviewrow)

Example code of how to determine a `DataGridViewRow` from a `DataRow` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your datarow have a primary key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `dataView.Find` on the row's primary key.

**EDIT**: To find the `DataGridViewRow` for a `DataRowView`, call `grid.Rows[dataView.IndexOf(drv))`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to use that. Could you provide a more complete/longer example?

Comment: You need to get the `DataView` that is bound to the grid.  This may be `table.DefaultView` or the grid's DataSource, depending on the grid and the binding.  Then, call `Find(row["PrimaryKeyColumn"])`.

Comment: so you mean "PrimaryKeyColumn" would be the column name like "Id" or "Name" instead of an actual value like "123" or "Fred".

Comment: Yes; it must be the DataTable's primary key.  This returns a `DataRowView`.

Comment: I'm needing a `DataGridViewRow` returned though, not a `DataRowView`.

Comment: Thank you, this looks to be what I want.. except I found out from an exception that there is "no Sort order is specified." :(

I found this on MSDN: "If you do not explicitly specify sort criteria for DataView, the DataRowView objects in DataView are sorted based on the index of its corresponding DataRow in the DataTable.Rows DataRowCollection." 

So, even though it's sorted by this index, there was still no sort order specified, so it wouldn't help me would it?

Comment: @dev: If there is no sort order, you can just get the index of the DataRow in its table (`table.IndexOf(row)`)

Comment: @developer: Sorry; `table.Rows.IndexOf`.

Comment: I think you meant table.Rows.IndexOf(row)? Thank you I believe this will work for me finally! :D